Finish one method before starting other method
I am writing C# Codes for my Unity Program.
I am getting data through IEnumerator searchInDatabase(string sql) function.
I will call getDatabaseValue() by pressing A.
Codes as follows.
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) getDatabaseValue("select * from table;", 0, 0);
}

IEnumerator searchInDatabase(string sql)
{
    queryCompleted = false;
    WWWForm database = new WWWForm();
    database.AddField("sqlpost", sql);
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("myDatabase", database))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        string[] entries = www.downloadHandler.text.Split(",|");
        result = new string[entries.Length, entries[0].Split(',').Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] parts = entries[i].Split(',');
            for (int j = 0; j < parts.Length; j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = parts[j];
            }
        }
        queryCompleted = true;
        yield return result;
    }
    Debug.Log("Query Completed");
}

public string getDatabaseValue(string sql, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.Log("Waiting 00");
        StartCoroutine(searchInDatabase(sql));
        Debug.Log("getting result data");
        return result[x, y];
    }
    finally { }
    //catch (Exception ex) { Debug.LogWarning(ex.StackTrace); }
  //  return result[0, 0];
 }

However, the result that I got is
Waiting 00
getting result data
Result = 1   // (<-- result from previous query statement) 
Query Completed

Which I expected that the result should be getting query finish first before getting data from result.
My expected output as follows:
Waiting 00
Query Completed
getting result data
Result = 2 //(<--result from this query statement)


Corutines are explicitly for running things asynchronously, so an out of order result is expected. I don't know the exact rules in Unity, and it abuses IEnumerable instead of the newer async/await-pattern. But it is probably your expectations that are incorrect.

try to make your question more concise and straight to the point. Start by removing any irrelevant code and only highlighting the code that you have trouble with

@JonasH Coroutines are not async at all but are running on the main thread ... they just get called MoveNext once a frame. This is handy for new coders for getting things to run quickly as it basically avoids having to deal with actually dispatching things back into the main thread (most Unity API can only be used on the Unity main thread) ... nowadays there are better alternatives like UniTask ... Unity is working on Awaitable but it isn't really catching up with R3 yet

@derHugo async is not the same as concurrent.  Corutines allows tasks to be suspended and resumed, and therefore allow tasks to be run asynchronously with regards to each other. The thread used is irrelevant. It is exactly the same as with async/await when used in a synchronizationcontext, both are examples of corutines. And as I understand it, Unity has some special methods to replicate await Task.Delay and webrequests in iterator blocks.

If using traditional coroutines, you cannot immediately get the result after calling StartCoroutine. What you can do is wait for the coroutine to complete and then process the result.
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        StartCoroutine(getDatabaseValue("select * from table;", 0, 0));
}

public IEnumerator getDatabaseValue(string sql, int x, int y)
{
    ....
    yield return StartCoroutine(searchInDatabase(sql, callback));
    // process result[x, y]
}


Since Unity 2023, you can use Awaitable to reimplement this. However, please note that with this method, after you press the key, your game will continue until the DB request is completed.
async Awaitable Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        await result = searchInDatabase("select * from table;", 0, 0);
    }
}

async Awaitable<string> searchInDatabase(string sql, int x, int y)
{
    //....
    var cs = new AwaitableCompletionSource();
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("myDatabase", database))
    {
        www.SendWebRequest().completed += _ => cs.SetResult();
        await cs.Awaitable;
        
        // process www results
        // ....
        
        return result[x, y];
    }
}


As an alternative to Awaitable I would also throw in UniTask for a seamless async integration with Unity API ... Awaitable is going there but Unity has a lot to do yet in order to catch up with R3 ;)

You used StartCoroutine to start a coroutine. The Description of coroutine in Unity is says:

The execution of a coroutine can be paused at any point using the yield statement. When a yield statement is used, the coroutine pauses execution and automatically resumes at the next frame. See the Coroutines documentation for more details.

So, when getDatabaseValue calls searchInDatabase, the method searchInDatabase will be paused at that line:
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

And then, program will return to getDatabaseValue, and continuely execute the next line:
Debug.Log("getting result data");

As a possible fix, you could yielding the return value of StartCoroutine like this:
yield return StartCoroutine(searchInDatabase(sql));

If you do this fix, you should check the code which calls getDatabaseValue if it has the same problem.
There is more information about this:
MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine
The first example in this page is similer to your code, and the second example is what you expect.

if you do this you don't have to use StartCoroutine at all but can simply do yield return searchInDatabase(sql);

StartCoroutine(searchInDatabase(sql)) indicates asynchronous execution, so when you start it, next lines of code after it are executed immediately and they execute faster than StartCoroutine(searchInDatabase(sql)), that's why you see the result.
For that you would need to synchronize better the operation, the easiest way would be to put the continuation inside searchInDatabase(sql):
IEnumerator searchInDatabase(string sql)
{
    queryCompleted = false;
    WWWForm database = new WWWForm();
    database.AddField("sqlpost", sql);

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("myDatabase", database))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        string[] entries = www.downloadHandler.text.Split(",|");
        result = new string[entries.Length, entries[0].Split(',').Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] parts = entries[i].Split(',');
            for (int j = 0; j < parts.Length; j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = parts[j];
            }
        }
        queryCompleted = true;
        yield return result;
    }
    Debug.Log("Query Completed");

    // Moved from getDatabaseValue
    Debug.Log("getting result data");
    yield return result[x, y];
}


Simple solution
Observer pattern
Use your coroutine in combination with events
Instead of (or after) queryCompleted = true;, invoke the event.
private event Action<string, int, int> QueryCompleted; // class-level event

private void OnEnable() {
    QueryCompleted += HandleQueryCompleted;
}

// OnDisable Unregister

private IEnumerator searchInDatabase(string sql)
{
    // ... UnityWebRequest, etc.
    QueryCompleted?.Invoke(sql, 0, 0); // or so
}

private void HandleQueryCompleted(string query, int x, int y) {
    // ...
}
    


I mean why not just pass in a delegate to the searchInDatabase instead? private IEnumerator searchInDatabase(string sql, Action<string> onResult)

that could work too. no one said not to do it, you're welcome to suggest your answer.
